# supervisorctl restart all ERROR (spawn error)

Tags: supervisord, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I install supervisor `sudo apt install supervisor`
I set wesocket.conf file in "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/websocket.conf".
In there

```
[program:websocket]
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/project/artisan websocket:serve
directory = /var/www/project
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
```

Then, I run the command blow

In my ssh cmd

```
root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# nano websocket.conf
root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisorctl update
websocket: stopped
websocket: updated process group
root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisorctl start websocket
websocket: ERROR (already started)
root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisorctl
websocket                        STARTING
supervisor> exit

root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisorctl restart all
websocket: stopped
websocket: ERROR (spawn error)
root@localhost:/etc/supervisor/conf.d#
```

** Where is wrong ** 
Please tip me 
*Thank*